# Positional argument after optional argument list

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I'm somewhat new to using argparse and have run into a problem stemming from using an optional argument (list of files arbitrarily long) along with a positional argument (a single file). Here is a simple program that demonstrates this problem:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("pos_file", help="Input file")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--optional_list", help="file list", nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I call this program using the command:

```
python test_arg_parse.py -l file1.txt file2.txt pos_file.txt
```

Argparse fails, mentioning that there are too few arguments. I understand why this is happening - argparse assumes that pos_file.txt is part of the optional list and therefore doesn't find a positional argument - but I don't understand why argparse doesn't always consider the last argument to be positional. This can be solved by placing the verbose argument between the optional list and the positional argument:

```
python test_arg_parse.py -l file1.txt file2.txt -v pos_file.txt
```

Which argparse happily processes. However, I don't want to enforce this strict ordering of arguments and I would like to keep the list optional and the single file positional. I have looked into using the `append` functionality, but it doesn't seem reasonable considering the list can be arbitrarily long.

Is there a nice way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I think you want [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#argparse), it is new in Python 3.7

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I use the `parse_intermixed_args()` function, I receive the following error: `TypeError: parse_intermixed_args: positional arg with nargs=...`. Which makes me believe that I cannot have a list of arbitrary length along with a positional argument.

Comment: "and I would like to keep the list optional and the single file positional". If this last one is to be in the end, after the optional, this is impossible to parse without more elaborated specification machinery. This is why Python function pos parameters have to come before optionals, You don't know how many optional args will be there. If you make your positional a not required arg, you can check its absence and capture it manually from the list end. But then the automatic help will not reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing is driven by the order of values in the command line, having first identified which strings look like flags (optionals) and which are just arguments.

```
python test_arg_parse.py -l file1.txt file2.txt pos_file.txt
```

It first checks the start of the list for positional arguments - none. Then for flags - it finds '-l'.  That takes '+', so it's given everything up to the next flag (or the end).  Now there's nothing left on the list for 'pos_file'.

There is a bug/issue about this, and I proposed a patch that would check the positionals, and hold back on giving the optional everything.  But that requires too much fiddling with the core parsing code, and hasn't gotten very far in approval process.

So for now, using a positional like this after an open ended argument (optionals or positionals) doesn't work

```
python test_arg_parse.py pos_file.txt -l file1.txt file2.txt
```

should work.  But if you want more control, define `pos_file` as a flagged argument, not a positional.

Comment: Hmm.. I worried about something like this. I will look into either enforcing that argument order or defining `pos_file` as a flagged argument. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As users noted, once you pass in a flag (optional) argument argparse will not know how to handle positional arguments that come afterwards. One solution I found is to use the pseudo-argument `--` which tells argparse that the next parameters are positional. From the [python argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing)

> If you have positional arguments that must begin with - and don’t look
> like negative numbers, you can insert the pseudo-argument '--' which
> tells parse_args() that everything after that is a positional argument

You can use the updated command:

```
python test_arg_parse.py -l file1.txt file2.txt -- pos_file.txt
```